# Running NGINX UNIT in Docker: Unit is running unprivileged, then it cannot use arbitrary user and group

Tags: docker, nginx-unit

The error I get is this:

```
    /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, launching Unit daemon to perform initial configuration... 2022/08/31 17:30:45 
[warn] 11#11 Unit is running unprivileged, then it cannot use arbitrary user and group. 2022/08/31 17:30:45 
[alert] 11#11 Unable to create certificates storage directory: mkdir(/var/lib/unit/certs/) failed (13: Permission denied) 2022/08/31 17:30:45 [alert] 11#11 bind(6, unix:/var/run/control.unit.sock.tmp) failed (13: Permission denied)
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
    FROM node:16 as BUILDER

    LABEL maintainer="NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>"

    USER root

    RUN set -ex \
        && apt-get update \
        && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y ca-certificates mercurial build-essential libssl-dev libpcre2-dev \
        && mkdir -p /usr/lib/unit/modules /usr/lib/unit/debug-modules \
        && hg clone https://hg.nginx.org/unit \
        && cd unit \
        && hg up 1.27.0 \
        && NCPU="$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)" \
        && DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH="$(dpkg-architecture -q DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)" \
        && CC_OPT="$(DEB_BUILD_MAINT_OPTIONS="hardening=+all,-pie" DEB_CFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND="-Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC" dpkg-buildflags --get CFLAGS)" \
        && LD_OPT="$(DEB_BUILD_MAINT_OPTIONS="hardening=+all,-pie" DEB_LDFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND="-Wl,--as-needed -pie" dpkg-buildflags --get LDFLAGS)" \
        && CONFIGURE_ARGS="--prefix=/usr \
                    --state=/var/lib/unit \
                    --control=unix:/var/run/control.unit.sock \
                    --pid=/var/run/unit.pid \
                    --log=/var/log/unit.log \
                    --tmp=/var/tmp \
                    --user=unit \
                    --group=unit \
                    --openssl \
                    --libdir=/usr/lib/$DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH" \
        && ./configure $CONFIGURE_ARGS --cc-opt="$CC_OPT" --ld-opt="$LD_OPT" --modules=/usr/lib/unit/debug-modules --debug \
        && make -j $NCPU unitd \
        && install -pm755 build/unitd /usr/sbin/unitd-debug \
        && make clean \
        && ./configure $CONFIGURE_ARGS --cc-opt="$CC_OPT" --ld-opt="$LD_OPT" --modules=/usr/lib/unit/modules \
        && make -j $NCPU unitd \
        && install -pm755 build/unitd /usr/sbin/unitd \
        && make clean \
        && ./configure $CONFIGURE_ARGS --cc-opt="$CC_OPT" --modules=/usr/lib/unit/debug-modules --debug \
        && ./configure nodejs --node-gyp=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin/node-gyp \
        && make -j $NCPU node node-install libunit-install \
        && make clean \
        && ./configure $CONFIGURE_ARGS --cc-opt="$CC_OPT" --modules=/usr/lib/unit/modules \
        && ./configure nodejs --node-gyp=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin/node-gyp \
        && make -j $NCPU node node-install libunit-install \
        && ldd /usr/sbin/unitd | awk '/=>/{print $(NF-1)}' | while read n; do dpkg-query -S $n; done | sed 's/^\([^:]\+\):.*$/\1/' | sort | uniq > /requirements.apt

    FROM node:16 as PRODUCTION
    COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
    COPY --from=BUILDER /usr/sbin/unitd /usr/sbin/unitd
    COPY --from=BUILDER /usr/sbin/unitd-debug /usr/sbin/unitd-debug
    COPY --from=BUILDER /usr/lib/unit/ /usr/lib/unit/
    COPY --from=BUILDER /requirements.apt /requirements.apt
    COPY --from=BUILDER /usr/lib/*-linux-gnu/libunit.a /tmp/
    COPY --from=BUILDER /usr/include/nxt_* /usr/include/
    COPY --from=BUILDER /usr/local/lib/node_modules/unit-http/ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/unit-http/
    USER root
    RUN set -x \
        && if [ -f "/tmp/libunit.a" ]; then \
            mv /tmp/libunit.a /usr/lib/$(dpkg-architecture -q DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)/libunit.a; \
            rm -f /tmp/libunit.a; \
        fi \
        && mkdir -p /var/lib/unit/ \
        && mkdir /docker-entrypoint.d/ \
        && addgroup --system unit \
        && adduser \
             --system \
             --disabled-login \
             --ingroup unit \
             --no-create-home \
             --home /nonexistent \
             --gecos "unit user" \
             --shell /bin/false \
             unit \
        && apt update \
        && apt --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y install curl $(cat /requirements.apt) \
        && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
        && rm -f /requirements.apt \
        && ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/unit.log

    STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM

    ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

    CMD ["sudo", "unitd", "--no-daemon", "--control", "unix:/var/run/control.unit.sock"]


    #FROM nginx/unit:1.27.0-node16

    EXPOSE 8080

    WORKDIR /usr/app

    # Copy in build artifacts, build project dependencies
    COPY src/frontend/dpia-webapp/package*.json ./
    RUN npm install -g sass
    RUN npm install
    RUN apt-get update && apt install make
    COPY src/frontend/dpia-webapp/. .
    RUN make compile
    COPY src/frontend/dpia-webapp/unitd-conf.json /docker-entrypoint.d/
    #RUN unitd --control 127.0.0.1:8224

    CMD ["unitd", "--no-daemon", "--control", "unix:/var/run/control.unit.sock", "--log", "/usr/app/unit.log"]
```

I am not sure why is NGINX Unit running in unprivileged mode? Is there a way to make it run priviliged

I believe it is failing at this line: CMD ["sudo", "unitd", "--no-daemon", "--control", "unix:/var/run/control.unit.sock"]

This docker file script is taken directly from NGINX UNIT docker script: https://github.com/nginx/unit/blob/master/pkg/docker/Dockerfile.node16

Comment: Is there any special use case why you are not just using 1.27.0-node16 as a new base image for your apps and add your layers (app, expose,etc) on top of it? I would recomand this as we are updating the Dockerfiles and with the NGINX Image as a base you will automatically get the updates. –

Answer (score 0):

You have a commented FROM line which therefor never executes:

```
    #FROM nginx/unit:1.27.0-node16
```

as a consequence, everything that follows is part of the same stage. And because of this your last CMD line:

```
    CMD ["unitd", "--no-daemon", "--control", "unix:/var/run/control.unit.sock", "--log", "/usr/app/unit.log"]
```

will overwrite the previous one:

```
    CMD ["sudo", "unitd", "--no-daemon", "--control", "unix:/var/run/control.unit.sock"]
```

So the one with `sudo` is actually never executed.

If you  fix this situation somehow, I think it will work. Either add `sudo` to the last CMD or just delete it.

Comment: the issue is with this error: Unit is running unprivileged, then it cannot use arbitrary user and group. somehow it does not work when it is running unprivileged. Not sure how to solve it.

Comment: I just gave you the solution... did you try it?